# Comparación entre un campo decimal y una variable date

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene un campo: `[falta_dot]` que es `decimal (8,0) null`  (EJ: `'20211231'`)
y tengo una variable: `declare @FPERIODO Date = '01/03/2022'`. Mi intención es generar un campo *[DIRENCIA MESES]* en donde me clasifique el campo *falta_dot* en relación a la variable `@FPERIODO` y si *falta_dot* es 6 meses menor a la variable entonces `[DIRENCIA MESES] = 'MENOR 6 MESES'` sino `[DIRENCIA MESES] = 'MAYOR 6 MESES'`.

Mi conocimiento llegó hasta acá y me da error

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,@FPERIODO,(FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),C.[falta_dot])),'dd/MM/yyyy'))) < 180 THEN 'MENOR 6 MESES' ELSE 'MAYOR 6 MESES'  END [DIRENCIA MESES]
```

Comment: `'01/03/2022'` es 1 de marzo o 3 de enero?

Comment: 01/03/2022 es 1 de marzo

Comment: ¿Tienen que ser meses completos o solo con que cambie el mes? ¿Cuanto es la diferencia entre Diciembre 31 y Enero 1? ¿Es la misma que la diferencia entre Diciembre 1 y Enero 31?

Comment: Si la diferencia entre [falta_dot] y @FPERIODO es mayor a 180 días  completar campo diferencia de meses  con "'MAYOR 6 MESES" sino "'MENOR a 6 MESES"

Answer (score 0):

```
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM,FORMAT(@FPERIODOF,'dd/MM/yyyy'),
(FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,convert(CHAR(8),C.[falta_dot])),'dd/MM/yyyy'))) > '6' 
THEN 'MENOR 6 MESES' ELSE 'MAYOR 6 MESES'  END [APERTURA MENOS SEIS MESES]
```

era un problema en el formato de la variable `@FPERIODO Date = '01/03/2022'` lo invertí y el valor de la diferencia es negativa por eso tuve que preguntar por >  no por < como había puesto. gracias